# Sampling text files with UNIX-style (0x0A) newlines

Tags: powershell

I need to sample the first N records of files which use UNIX-style (0x0A) newlines.

It is easy enough to use `Get-Content -First 3` to get the first three (3) lines. However, when `Out-File` writes them it uses Windows-style newlines.

How can I write the first N lines to a file using the newline style of the source file?

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\filefile1.txt
123
456
789
012
345
PS C:\src\t> Format-Hex -Path .\filefile1.txt

   Label: C:\src\t\filefile1.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 31 32 33 0A 34 35 36 0A 37 38 39 0A 30 31 32 0A 123�456�789�012�
0000000000000010 33 34 35 0A                                     345�
```

A file produced through Out-File replaces the 0A newlines with 0D0A line endings.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\filefile1.txt -First 3 | Out-File -Path .\filefile2.txt -Encoding ascii
PS C:\src\t> Format-Hex -Path .\filefile2.txt

   Label: C:\src\t\filefile2.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 31 32 33 0D 0A 34 35 36 0D 0A 37 38 39 0D 0A    123��456��789��
```

Using the `-NoNewline` switch removes -all- newlines.

```
PS C:\src\t> Get-Content -Path .\filefile1.txt | Out-File -FilePath .\filefile2.txt -Encoding ascii -NoNewline
PS C:\src\t> Format-Hex -Path .\filefile2.txt

   Label: C:\src\t\filefile2.txt

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 34 35    123456789012345

PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.1
```

Comment: duplicates: [UNIX format files with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5102115/995714), [Prevent trailing newline in PowerShell Out-File command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35279848/995714), [How can I keep UNIX LF line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60157755/995714)

Comment: @phuclv, yes, the last link I think will answer this.  I think I know the person who wrote that question. :-)